# How to get rid of this developer window in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I must have clicked something and have a developer tool open in Firefox that I can't find a way to close, and it's taking up a good portion of the right side of my browser window.  I've taken a screenshot of it. Is there a way to get rid of this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There should be a x at the upper right corner of the page click it otherwise simply click on the tool and hit <kbd>Escape</kbd>

[image]

Comment: It's in the bottom right corner or the page, though. o.o'

Comment: There are two [x] buttons.